# makeindex: how to avoid format inappropriately applied to comma between adjacent page numbers?

Tags: makeindex, makeidx

Suppose you have a document in which you want to index the word "x" on pages 1, 2, and 4, and you would like to style each of the page number entries in the index in the same way (perhaps each of them is a reference to a definition).  Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\colorred}[1]{{\color{red}{#1}}}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\chapter{Theory}

x\index{x|colorred}

\newpage

x\index{x|colorred}

\newpage

y

\newpage

x\index{x|colorred}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The result will be the index entry

[image: index entry]

in which the page number format --- the color red --- is applied to the first comma.  (In my application, the format I am using is a background color, which makes the appearance even worse.  I'm using a foreground color here for simplicity.)

Is there an elegant way to work around this feature?  The only way I have found is to trick `makeidx` into thinking that the formats for the consecutive numbers are different by defining a second macro

```
\newcommand{\colorrojo}[1]{{\color{red}{#1}}}
```

that has the same effect as `\colorred`, and writing `x\index{x|colorred}` on page 1 and `x\index{x|colorrojo}` on page 2.  That works (the first comma in the index entry, like the second, is black), but it doesn't seem like the right way to do things.

Comment: You may call `makeindex -r` to disable range formation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to call `makeindex` with the `-r` command line option that disable automatic range formation.

Otherwise, but it seems overkill, process the argument of `\colorred`:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\colorred}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \textcolor{red}{##1} }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { ,~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\chapter{Theory}

x\index{x|colorred}

\newpage

x\index{x|colorred}

\newpage

y

\newpage

x\index{x|colorred}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Note that generally `\textcolor{red}{word}` is preferable to `{\color{red}word}`.

[image]

Comment: Very nice!  My book uses `hyperref`, which I now see makes a difference: the page numbers get formatted like  `\hyperindexformat{\colorred}{1, 2}`.  I tried to adapt your code by saying `\let\oldhyperindexformat\hyperindexformat` and then `\RenewDocumentCommand{\hyperindexformat}{ m m }` followed by `\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #2 }`, `\seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \exp_not:N \oldhyperindexformat{#1}{##1} }`, and then the last line of your code, with `\newcommand{\colorred}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}`. But that doesn't work.  Do I have the argument numbers wrong? Or worse?

Comment: Compiling this does not give the desired output. Kindly review the code.

Comment: @azetina Thanks for noting. This had to do with a change in the working of `\seq_set_map:NNn`