# Change , to - in index

Tags: indexing, makeindex

How to change `,` to `-` in `index` between  the `number of the pages`?

[image]

**My minimal file:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true, colorlinks, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan] {hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\chapter{test1}
\index{topology}
\chapter{test2}
\index{topology}
\index{continue}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: @egreg makes some sorcery here, take a look:https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523755/10898

Comment: Thanks dear azentina and dear egreg.
Ive used a lot of \index{text} in my book so I should change them.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a way to indicate a page span in the index.  That is done by putting the code `|(` at the end of the index entry for the first page on which the entry appears (as `\index{test|(}`), and `|)` at the end of the entry for the last page on which it appears.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear barbara beeton. You are right. It fixed.